# AES CMAC calculation - output length for host cryptogram incorrect length

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle, globalplatform

I have below function which is supposed to return 8 byte host cryptogram based on length of derived data "L" but I am getting 16 bytes data. Although key is 128 bits, I was expecting BC AESCMAC function will return data based on value of L in the derivation data. If this is not the case, do I need to extract MS 8  Bytes from output. Below is my function -

```
private String scp03CalculatehostCryptogram(byte[] derivedSMACSessionKey, String hostChallenge, String cardChallenge) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, UnsupportedEncodingException {


    // Reference : GPC_2.2_D_SCP03_v1.1.1  > 6.2.2.3 Host Authentication Cryptogram - The host cryptogram (8 bytes) is calculated using the data derivation scheme defined in section 4.1.5 with the session key S-MAC and the derivation constant set to “host authentication cryptogram generation”. The length of the cryptogram shall be reflected in the parameter “L” (i.e. '0040').       The “context” parameter shall be set to the concatenation of the host challenge (8 bytes) and the card challenge (8 bytes).

     String labelForSMAC = "000000000000000000000001";
     String separationIndicator = "00"; 
     String lInteger = "0040";
     String counter = "01";
     String context = hostChallenge.concat(cardChallenge);

     String hostCryptogramDerivationData = labelForSMAC.concat(separationIndicator).concat(lInteger).concat(counter).concat(context);

     byte[] hostCryptogramDerivationDataBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(hostCryptogramDerivationData);

    System.out.println(" Host Cryptogram Derivation data : "+DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(hostCryptogramDerivationDataBytes));

 Mac aescmac = Mac.getInstance("AESCMAC", "BC");
    SecretKey scpENCKeyObject = new SecretKeySpec(derivedSMACSessionKey, "AES");
    aescmac.init(scpENCKeyObject);
    aescmac.update(hostCryptogramDerivationDataBytes);
     byte[] hostCryptogram = aescmac.doFinal();
     System.out.println(" Calculated Host Cryptogram : "+DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(hostCryptogram));
     return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(hostCryptogram);

    }
```

Output :

Host Cryptogram Derivation data : 0000000000000000000000010000400161BD435249EC20B7AA984A2D47AD4302
 Calculated Host Cryptogram : 6F405B9FD1438A4633A4289B618A1FB5

Example -  derived smac session key : 47297387E512687FBEB37D1C1F4B8F4C

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: From [RFC4493](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4493): "By default, the length of the output of AES-CMAC is 128 bits (16 bytes)."

Comment: yeah, I forgot to mention that Global platform External authenticate command requires only 8 byte of cryptogram. I am not able to find if cryptogram is Most significant 8 bytes or least significant 8 bytes of AES-CMAC. I am using SCP03. 
Is there a significance of parameter L if your comment is true

Comment: It's the leftmost bytes, i.e. the bytes with the lowest index. If you call that least or most significant depends on the endianess, of course. For Java they are the most significant.

Comment: Thanks Maarten. Please can you also confirm if rest of the code above is correct to calculate cryptogram?  Thanks

Comment: I forgot to ask original question.. what significance L has in this case if output is not as per length defined by L

Comment: Any help reply of above question **what significance L has in this case if output is not as per length defined by L** ?

Comment: Hey, easy. Note that the definition of L in your question is somewhere at the end of a code comment. Most monitors won't even show it. If you don't get any answers, please first check the question and ask yourself why everything is so quiet. And please understand that this isn't something we do as a job; getting answers is nice, but you cannot *rely* on SO to deliver.

Comment: yeah. I have moved forward and coded to considered leftmost 8 bytes but was trying to understand if BC function is not working as expected based on value of L. Thanks and appreciate your help as you are an expert in this area! I am a bit new to this so in future I will wait... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The length L is included in the input of the crytogram to make the output of the cryptogram as specific as possible.

Obviously the MAC algorithm won't pay any respect to the input. A MAC simply takes a key, input and then produces a predefined amount of data. *Your function* is supposed to create the cryptogram. This cryptogram requires the size of the output data L as parameter. So if you're not producing the required amount of output data then that's *up to you*.

And yes, in general if an output of a PRF (e.g. your function) needs to be resized then the leftmost bytes are taken.

Comment: Thanks Maarten. I will consider letmost 8 bytes in this case.